# File "D:\datasend.py", line 36, in <module> s.send(message) TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface in python 3.4.1

Tags: winapi

## Send some data to remote server

message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"

try :
    #Set the whole string
    s.send(message)
except socket.error:
    #Send failed
    print ('Send failed')
    sys.exit()

print ('Message send successfully')

## Now receive data

reply = s.recv(4096)

print ('reply')

Comment: It is very unclear what you are actually asking. If you want to resolve the error, just search the web what that error means first, so that you can ask informed questions. Other than that, please provide the code, what you expected it to do and what it did instead.

Comment: i want to communicate with google server to send some data and receive some data. socket is created without any problem. but in "try :
    #Set the whole string
    s.sendall(message)
except socket.error:
    #Send failed
    print ('Send failed')
    sys.exit()"

Comment: in the line "s.sendall(message) " i am getting "  File "D:\python Codes\datasend.py", line 36, in <module>
    s.send(message)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface" error. could you please resolve?

Comment: Please go back and edit your question instead of trying to add comments to clarify it. Also check out the various possibilities of formatting, e.g. for code.